# Clarification on clock synchronization passage from Kleppner and Kolenkow

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time

I have a question about the following passage from *An Introduction to Mechanics* by Kleppner and Kolenkow. The passage reads as follows:

> The Newtonian procedure would work if the speed of light were infinite or so large that it could be regarded as infinite. However, if one accepts that signals can propagate no faster than the speed of light, the procedure is wrong in principle. For instance, a signal from the Moon to the Earth takes about one second. One might attempt to synchronize a clock on the Moon with a clock on the Earth by advancing the Moon clock by one second. With this adjustment, the Moon clock would always appear to agree with the Earth clock. However, for the observer on the Moon, the Earth clock would always lag the Moon clock by two seconds. Thus the clocks would be synchronized for one observer but not the other.
>
> Einstein proposed a simple procedure for synchronizing clocks so that all observers agree on the time of an event. Observer $A$ sends observer $B$ a signal at time $T_{A}$. Observer $B$ notes that the signal arrives at time $T_{B}$ on the local clock. $B$ immediately sends a signal back to $A$ who detects it at time $T_{A}' = T_{A} + \Delta T$. The clocks are synchronized if $B$’s clock reads $T_{B} = T_{A} + \Delta T/2$. Interpreting the times reported by different observers requires knowing their positions, but everyone would agree on the time of an event. (pg. 445)

How is the content in the first paragraph any different from Einstein's procedure? With the case of the moon, let $T_{A} = 0$. It takes a second for the signal to get the moon. This will be $T_{B}$ in Moon time (MT). If the observer on the moon retransmits the signal instantaneously, $T_{A}'$ must be $2$, which means that $\Delta T = 2$, and hence $T_{B}$ must be $1$. Is this not the same as advancing the Moon's clock by a second? I hope someone could clarify — many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not interpreting the described Newtonian procedure correctly. The moon clock is one second ahead of the earth clock so that seen from the earth the two tell the same time. But seen from the moon the earth clock is two seconds slow so the procedure has not produced a situation where both observers think the two clocks are synchronized. The Einstein procedure does produce this agreement.

Comment: Okay, would you mind helping me in resolving my confusion? Suppose the Earth clock is stopped exactly at 1 second while the moon clock is at 0 second. Let's say that there's an explosion on the Earth at local time t = 1. By the time this wavefront reaches moon, the moon clock will also read t = 1. If a similar explosion happens on the moon (at local time t = 0), the wavefront will reach the earth at local time 2 and so the moon observer thinks that Earth clock lags by two seconds. I think this makes sense. What I can't seem to see clearly is why Einstein's procedure produces an agreement.

Comment: Actually, I think I understand. So, instead of the above procedure, Einstein tells us to put Earth clock at 0 and moon clock at 1. Then, we send a signal from earth (ET = 0) to moon. As soon as the moon receives the signal at MT = 1, we start the moon clock and retransmit the signal. This signal arrives at ET = MT = 2. Henceforth, any signal sent back and forth will read the same time, locally on the Moon and the Earth. Is this a better understanding?

Comment: Yes I think that is correct. Your argument introduces the dangerous concept of simultaneity of distant events, but I think you have understood how the Einstein procedure produces agreement that the clocks are synchronized. (The whole argument really only works if the two observers are relatively at rest, in which case the simultaneity issue would not arise)